# GORM: Add limit to nested preload of association just doesn't work?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm trying to limit the members for each collection to 8, although no luck?

It seems to ignore my code completely, does not add any `LIMIT` syntax to the final SQL.

Here is my query:

```golang
var error = database.
        Model(Collection{}).
        Preload("Members.Data", func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
            return db.Limit(8)
    }).
        Where("id != 1").
        Find(&collections).
        Error
```

I can preload members, limit then preload data, but it's selecting the members as `IN` so it will limit all members no matter the collection id.